# Передача параметра через адрес подключаемого скрипта

Tags: javascript

Подскажите,пожалуйста.
Необходимо скрипту передать id, который будет прописан в виде :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="скрипт.js?id=17"></script>
```

что бы потом подставлять этот id в URL адрес, формирующийся java скриптом

Суть в том, что на сайте есть партнерская программа. Что бы отслеживать движения по баннеру, в url передается id партнера (аффилата).

весь скрипт уже готов, но никак не могу захватить id по адресу(((

Comment: Может alert(id); отобразит id?

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт на PHP, то:

- в .htaccess:

  `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .js`
- в script.js:

  `<?php
      $id = intval($_GET['id']);
      // Возможно другие действия
  ?>
  ...
  client.id = <?=$id ?>
  ...`

Ещё можно использовать [SSI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29):

- в .htaccess:

  `AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .js`
- в script.js:

  `...
  client.id = <!--#echo var="QUERY_STRING"--> 
  ...`
- на странице:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="скрипт.js?17"></script>`

Только это неправильный подход. Если ваше мероприятие будет достаточно масштабным, вам будет целесообразнее отдавать всем **одинаковый** скрипт, а id устанавливать в коде на странице:

```
<script>
    client = {
      id: 17,
      // Возможно другие параметры
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://......./скрипт.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tmp = new Array();      
var tmp2 = new Array();     
var param = new Array();
var get = $('script[src*="скрипт.js"]').attr('src').replace(/[^\?]+\?/, '');
if(get != '') {
    tmp = (get.substr(1)).split('&');   
    for(var i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');       
        param[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];       // пары ключ(имя переменной)->значение
    }

    for (var key in param) {
        var id = key

    }
}
```

вот так будет работать. загвоздка была в

```
var get = $('script[src*="скрипт.js"]').attr('src').replace(/[^\?]+\?/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Получение скрипта без jQuery и с поддержкой старых браузеров

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    len = scripts.length,
    re = /скрипт\.js$/,
    src, myScriptSrc;

while (len--) {
  src = scripts[len].src;
  if (src && src.match(re)) {
    myScriptSrc = src;
    break;
  }
}
```