# Как сделать перенаправление через параметр в адресе подключаемого скрипта?

Tags: javascript, redirect, редирект

Хотелось бы найти скрипт, который позволяет делать перенаправление в таком виде:

> `site.ru/some.js?site.com`

То есть при обращении к скрипту с особым параметром идёт перенаправление.
Может есть где готовый скрипт?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача параметра через адрес подключаемого скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/153029/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из текущего скрипта его полный путь можно узнать через:

> `document.currentScript.src`

но, к сожалению, **[`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)** не поддерживается IE (хотя поддерживается MS Edge).

Если же вам нужно, чтобы поддерживалось всеми обозревателями сети, то у вас **есть три пути:**

**1-ый путь**

Здесь мы обрабатываем путь в котором возможно находится искомый параметр сразу после загрузки скрипта по нему в следующем за ним скрипте.

```
<script id="my-script" type="text/javascript" src="script.js?redirectPath=https://google.com"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var src = document.getElementById('my-script').src;
src = src.slice(src.indexOf('?redirectPath'));
if(src.length > 1) // если redirectPath найдено
    location = src.slice(src.indexOf('=') + 1);
</script>
```

**2-ой путь**

В случае, если вы можете писать перед скриптом, то передачу параметра в скрипт мы не совершаем, а делаем перенаправление перед загрузкой скрипта.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var redirectPath = 'https://google.com';
if(redirectPath)
    location = redirectPath;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

**3-ий путь**

Здесь понадобится сервер на PHP (можно JSP, ASP и прочие), который будет создавать JS-файл и вписывать в него переданный параметр. Хорошо это тем, что это будет поддерживаться всеми обозревателями сети и обработка будет из текущего JS-скрипта. Считывание параметра в PHP будет через обращение к `$_GET['redirectPath']`. А сам параметр будет передаваться, к примеру, так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.php?redirectPath=https://google.com"></script>
```